# How to use optional unwrapping and a boolean condition in a single if condition

Tags: swift, boolean, option-type

I want to check whether an object is type of `NSNumber` and a boolean variable is `true` or not in a single statement. 
For this I wrote as below:

```
let someBool = ...
if value.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary) {
   // do something with dict
}
else if (let number = value as? NSNumber) && someBool{
  //Do something with number
}
else {
  // do something here
}
```

But, its throwing error like 'pattern variable binding cannot appear in an expression'.

How to use optional unwrapping and a boolean condition in a single `if` condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `where` clause:

```
if let number = value as? NSNumber where someBool {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yeah solved this, can you tell me how this where works?

Comment: The `if let` is evaulated first, if `value` can be cast to `NSNumber` then it will be checked whether `someBool` is `true`; in that case the code inside the braces is run. Source: http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/

Answer (score 1):

ABakerSmith's answer is perfect.

I just want to share how to achieve the same result using the powerful Swift `switch` statement.

```
switch value {
case let dictionary as NSDictionary:
    println("do something with dictionary")
case let number as NSNumber where someBool:
    println("do something with number")
default: println("do something here")
}
```